# Alternative expressions for "there's a possibility of something"

Tags: idioms, expressions, idiomatic-language

I usually say "*there is a possibility of ...*" to describe something that can still happen anytime later, but I don't think this is the only way to describe it.

The problem is that, while searching for synonyms of an individual word is fairly easy, finding alternative *expression* is quite tricky solely using a search engine. Could anyone suggest me some alternative ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say this in many different ways. A complete sentence would make it much easier to point out other alternatives.

You have to look at synonyms of "possibility" to actually build similar expressions.

From the top of my head, here are few alternatives:

- there is a chance that ...
- there is little likelihood that ...
- it is quite likely that ...
- there is a high probability that ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want an exact equivalent (such that whatever follows wouldn't have to be changed to make sense) alternatives could be:

- There is a chance of...
- There is a risk of/danger of... (for bad things)

Let's say the original phrase is "There is a possibility of rain" (note that **rain** is a noun rather than a verb).
You could add "rain" to those and it would work the same.

As AIQ says, there are more alternatives and it revolves around finding words that mean the same as "possibility". For some of these, you would have to use a verb structure.

"There is a chance that it will rain"